# SQL match multiple columns when both columns match ANY entry in a different table

Tags: sql

I have two tables (below). I am trying to return the entry of `TABLE B` when BOTH columns match ANY of the items in `TABLE A`.

In the tables below, I'd like to return the following,

`Expected Result`

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| userB | userA |
| userC | userB |

`TABLE A`

| name |
| --- |
| userA |
| userB |
| userC |

`TABLE B`

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| userA | x |
| userB | userA |
| y | userC |
| z | t |
| userC | userB |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT T1.*
FROM TableB AS T1
    INNER JOIN TableA AS T2
        ON T1.from = T2.name
    INNER JOIN TableA AS T3
        ON T1.to = T3.name
```

The idea is that you first get every record from TableB where it's first column (from) matches any record from TableA.

Then, you filter that result by those records from TableB where it's second column (to) matches any record from TableA.

**EDIT**

Another approach could be:

```sql
Select *
from TableB AS T1
where T1.from in (select distinct name from TableA)
    and T1.to in (select distinct name from TableA)
```

But I'm not sure that would be more efficient.

It would be even better if you did a `with` statement instead of `(select distinct name from TableA)`.

Comment: That appears to work, thank you. Do you know if there is a more efficient way to do it? In my case, `TableA` is extremely large.

Comment: I'm not aware of any more efficient way to do it. Perhaps if `TableA` has many duplicate values it would be better to do a `with` statement to select the distinct values first, and then use the resulting table instead of `TableA`.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include a second approach.